# Api call from LWC. "TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to make API call to some open APIs and getting the same error every time:
"TypeError: Failed to fetch". The site is added to CSP trusted sites and CORS allowed origin list. The code is working properly in LWC Playground and I can make this call from Postman. Below is my code:

```
let endpoint = 'https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Any';

        let requestParams = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'//,
                //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
            }
        };

        fetch(endpoint, requestParams)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('in response');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error3: ' + error);
            });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right answer is that I left checked one default CSP Directive only (it was "Allow site for img-src") for the site. When I checked all the others directives in 10 min I got a response (CSP takes time to start work)
[image]